# Android Studio: move a activity to separate java class

Tags: java, android

my original code is provide as below:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageView;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
Uri imageUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    final ImageView exampleImage = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.exampleImageView);
    exampleImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [TODO] Implement application behavior when the user clicks the profile picture
            //Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            GalleryActivity();
        }
    });
}
private void GalleryActivity(){
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }

}
```

....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
I want to move the GallertyActivity to another separate class.
I did it by copying some parts to the new class. but it show some error, what did I do wrong?

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GalleryActivity {
ImageView imageView;
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
Uri imageUri;

private void GalleryActivity(){
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }

}

}
```

error message:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
        ^
  symbol:   method startActivityForResult(Intent,int)
  location: class GalleryActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few problems here

1. the `GalleryActivity` class does not extend `AppCompatActivity` (or any other class)
2. the `GalleryActivity` function should a) start with a lowercase letter and b) belongs in the `ProfileActivity` class
3. the onActivityResult callback also belongs in the `ProfileActivity` class

These points are based on assumptions I've made about your intentions given the info you've provided

Comment: I now only keep the GalleryActivity.java as " public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompact Activity......... start ActivityForResult()"   but now it says  error: invalid method declaration; return type required startActivityForResult()"  how to solve it?